# KafkaException: Could not instantiate class JsonDeserializer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm trying to start Spring Boot application with Kafka client following [this reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html) and I'm getting the error below.
Could you please advise how to fix?

```
@Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfig() {
    final HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap.servers"));
    result.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class);
    result.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    return result;
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<Long, String> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfig());
}

@Bean
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Long, String> containerFactory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    containerFactory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    containerFactory.setConcurrency(3);
    containerFactory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
    return containerFactory;
}
```

--

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.kafka.config.internalKafkaListenerEndpointRegistry'; nested exception is org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
    at com.ubs.wma.bmss.BmssConsumerApp.main(BmssConsumerApp.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:703) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:553) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createKafkaConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:73) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.createConsumer(DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory.java:69) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.<init>(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:305) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.<init>(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:230) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer.doStart(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:180) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:202) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.doStart(ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java:124) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.start(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:202) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.startIfNecessary(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:287) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.java:236) ~[spring-kafka-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Could not instantiate class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:316) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:203) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.<init>(KafkaConsumer.java:632) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils can not access a member of class org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer with modifiers "protected"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:436) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:314) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar:na]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Don't just dump a stacktrace without context, config and code and expect help...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to that documentation we have:

> for more complex or particular cases, the `KafkaConsumer`, and therefore `KafkaProducer`, provides overloaded constructors to accept `(De)Serializer` instances for keys and/or values, respectively.
>
> To meet this API, the `DefaultKafkaProducerFactory` and `DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory` also provide properties to allow to inject a custom `(De)Serializer` to target `Producer/Consumer`.

And further Apache Kafka JavaDocs:

```
/**
 * A producer is instantiated by providing a set of key-value pairs as configuration, a key and a value {@link Serializer}.
 * Valid configuration strings are documented <a href="http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs">here</a>.
 * Values can be either strings or Objects of the appropriate type (for example a numeric configuration would accept
 * either the string "42" or the integer 42).
 * @param configs   The producer configs
 * @param keySerializer  The serializer for key that implements {@link Serializer}. The configure() method won't be
 *                       called in the producer when the serializer is passed in directly.
 * @param valueSerializer  The serializer for value that implements {@link Serializer}. The configure() method won't
 *                         be called in the producer when the serializer is passed in directly.
 */
public KafkaProducer(Map<String, Object> configs, Serializer<K> keySerializer, Serializer<V> valueSerializer) {
```

So, what you need is like this:

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<Long, String> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfig(), null, new JsonDeserializer(Foo.class));
}
```

The problem that `JsonDeserializer` can't be instantiated by the reflection because it needs particular type to deserialize to.

Answer (score 2):

firts delete this configuration in your properties

```
    @Bean
public Map<String, Object> consumerConfig() {
    final HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    result.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, env.getProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap.servers"));
    //result.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, LongDeserializer.class);
    //result.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    return result;
}
```

now modifie this configuration to

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<Long, String> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfig(), new LongDeserializer(), new JsonDeserializer(YourClass.class));
}
```

JsonDesrializer And LongDeserializer are respectivly imported from

```
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.LongDeserializer;
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try add to faster.xml dependency to the pom.xml. It solves in my case.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
```